# React Charts line chart with grouped labels like months, weeks

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Is there any possibility to render a line chart with recharts with grouped points, lets say i have 6 months data series per day, about 180 days, which will represent 180 points in the chart, but the label in the X axis would show every month the data beholds to, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr..., something like the google CRM stock.

[image]

I have some code that formats the labels to get the month name, but it shows repeated, i want to show a single label per month.

```
    const formatXAxis = (tickItem) => {

        const d = new Date(tickItem);
        return d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    };
    const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
        render () {
            return (
        <LineChart width={800} height={400} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis tickFormatter={formatXAxis} dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add an interval to the xaxis configuration.

```
<XAxis interval={30} tickFormatter={formatXAxis} dataKey="name"/>
```